# What's wrong with aligning the initialization code?

Tags: javascript, code-formatting

From [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Code_formatting#Code_formatting):

> Long identifiers or values present problems for aligned initialization
>   lists, so always prefer non-aligned initialization. For example:

```
CORRECT_Object.prototype = {
  a: 0,
  b: 1,
  lengthyName: 2
};
```

> Not like this:

```
WRONG_Object.prototype = {
  a          : 0,
  b          : 1,
  lengthyName: 2
};
```

The wrong one looks better.
I do not understand what kind of problems they are talking about.
In what way inserting a couple of tabs before the colon could hurt my code?

Comment: _"The wrong one looks better."_ - In your opinion; I'm kind of on the fence on this one though I lean a little bit towards the "correct" one (and that's how I do it). It obviously makes no difference as to whether the code will _work._ If you prefer the "wrong" style and don't mind the extra effort to type it that way then go right ahead with it.

Comment: Adding an `evenLongerName` would require realigment of all existing properties. So would removing or renaming `lengthyName`.

Comment: @DCoder +1 - when the list gets bigger it quickly becomes a PITA adding new variable initialisations where the length of the name is longer than any already there. Also adding new ones in there is just quicker to type when not having to add all those extra spaces.

Comment: It rather depends on whether you use an IDE that will automatically reformat for you, and whether other folks will have to work with the code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing *wrong* with either.. Its more a personal preference than anything. Avoiding those extra tab/space characters, will shave some bytes off the file size, but if you are using some kind of minifier or compressor, it shouldn't matter as these *extra* characters will be stripped off. So you should probably stick to what you like best as it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it's not as easy to tell which key on the left goes with which value on the right when they're so far apart.

You could compromise and use a TAB stop for the alignment, so most values will be aligned but there won't be any huge horizontal spaces.